# Given a word, how to tell whether it is a Roman numeral?

Tags: integers

If I have a word that consists of letters I, V, X, L, C, D, M, how can I tell whether it is a valid roman numeral? For example, how do I tell that IXXL is not valid?

Comment: You can draw a syntax diagram. It should break down neatly into four successive phases, for thousands, hundreds, tens and units, the last three being similar in structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ease the description you can consider the pairs "IV", "IX", "XL", "XC", "CD" and "CM" as single symbols.

That is, the roman numerals are sequences made of these symbols: I, IV, V, IX, X, XL, L, XC, C, CD, D, CM, M.

The sequences must hold these rules:

- The symbols I, X, C, M can be repeated up to three consecutive times. Other symbols must not be repeated.
- In each sequence, the symbols appear in decreasing order.
- If a symbol with two letters occurs, none of these two letters occur after it, with the followinf exceptions: after XL and XC there can be IX; and after CD and CM there can be XC.

This way, your example is not legal because IX < XL, or because after IX there must not be any letter X.

Comment: "If a symbol with two letters occurs, none of these two letters occur after it." is not right. For example 99 - XCIX. After 'XC' there occurs 'X'.

Comment: These are “modern” rules: in Roman inscriptions one can find “IIXX” for 18 (Latin *duodeviginti*), possibly because “IIXX” takes a bit less space than “XVIII”. Repetition of more than three of the main symbols I C M was also allowed. Sticking to a consistent set of rules was not of a concern for the ancient Romans, who were not very proficient in arithmetic.

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak The pair “IX” should be considered as a single symbol. Probably the third rule should be better phrased.

Comment: What about pairs like XM or IC?

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak Thank you for your pointing. I have changed the third rule.

Comment: @spiderface These pairs are not allowed, at least in the modern standard. To write 990. the correct expression is CMXC.